# If $\frac{\tan(a+b-c)}{\tan(a-b+c)}=\frac{\tan c}{\tan b}$, then $\sin(b-c)=0$ or $\sin 2a + \sin2b + \sin 2c=0$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

If $$\frac{\tan (\alpha + \beta - \gamma )}{\tan (\alpha - \beta + \gamma )}=\frac{\tan \gamma}{\tan \beta}$$
then prove 
$$\sin (\beta - \gamma)=0$$
or $$\sin 2\alpha + \sin2\beta + \sin 2\gamma =0$$
here my try goes -

To prove $\sin (\beta - \gamma)=0$, sin x = 0, only when x = 0 or 360 degree, but for the sake of simplicity let's take x = 0, then we've to prove that $\beta - \gamma =0$ or $\beta = \gamma$.

Now,

If $\beta = \alpha$, then first equation will be $\frac{\tan \alpha}{\tan \alpha}= \frac{\tan\gamma}{\tan\beta}$ 
or $\frac{\tan\gamma}{\tan\beta}=1$

and

$$\frac{\tan x}{\tan y}=1$$, only if $$\tan x = \tan y$$

So, also in this case $\tan \gamma$ must be equal to $\tan \beta$ so, as to prove that $\sin (\beta - \gamma)=0$.

So, how to prove that $\beta = \gamma$?

and how to solve the second part of the question here?

Comment: Hitting the problem with *Mathematica*, the tangent equation reduces to $$\sin(\beta-\gamma)\left(\sin 2\alpha+\sin 2\beta+\sin 2\gamma \right) = 0$$ (There's probably a clever way to get to that. In any case...) The correct conclusion would seem to be that $\sin(\beta-\gamma)= 0$ **OR** (not "and") $\sin 2\alpha+\sin 2\beta + \sin 2\gamma = 0$.

Comment: @blue what's Mathematica?

Comment: Wow that's incredible

Comment: [*Mathematica*](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) is a powerful computer algebra system that makes trig manipulations like this one fairly trivial. An online counterpart exists as [WolframAlpha](http://wolframalpha.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's define $\mu := \frac12(\beta+\gamma)$ and $\nu:=\frac12(\beta-\gamma)$, so that we have
$$\frac{\tan(\alpha+2\nu)}{\tan(\alpha-2\nu)} = \frac{\tan(\mu-\nu)}{\tan(\mu+\nu)} \quad\to\quad
\frac{\sin(\alpha+2\nu)\cos(\alpha-2\nu)}{\sin(\alpha-2\nu)\cos(\alpha+2\nu)}=\frac{\sin(\mu-\nu)\cos(\mu+\nu)}{\sin(\mu+\nu)\cos(\mu-\nu)}$$
The identity
$$\sin(p\pm q)\cos(p \mp q) = \sin p \cos p \pm \sin q \cos q = \frac12( \sin 2p \pm \sin 2q) \tag{$\star$}$$
gives us
$$\frac{\sin 2\alpha + \sin 4\nu}{\sin 2\alpha - \sin 4 \nu} 
= \frac{\sin 2\mu - \sin 2 \nu }{\sin 2 \mu + \sin 2\nu}$$ 
so that, upon cross-multiplying and combining terms,
$$\begin{align}
0 &= \sin 2\alpha \cdot 2 \sin 2\nu + \sin 4\nu \cdot 2\sin 2\mu \\
&= \sin 2\alpha \cdot 2 \sin 2\nu + 2\sin 2\nu \cos 2\nu \cdot 2\sin 2\mu \\  
&= 2\sin 2\nu\left(\; \sin 2\alpha + 2\sin2\mu\cos 2\nu \;\right) \\  
&= 2\sin(\beta-\gamma)\left(\; \sin 2\alpha + 2\sin(\beta+\gamma)\cos(\beta-\gamma) \;\right) \\  
&= 2\sin(\beta-\gamma)\left(\; \sin 2\alpha + \sin 2 \beta + \sin 2\gamma  \;\right) \qquad\text{(using $(\star)$ again)} \\  
\end{align}$$

Therefore,
$$\sin(\beta-\gamma) = 0 \qquad\text{or}\qquad \sin 2\alpha + \sin 2 \beta + \sin 2\gamma = 0$$
$\square$

Comment: You know Wolfram is cooool. I never expected such thing. I'm trying to make my own trignometeric Wolfram which uses AI to solve the problems 

Comment: Wolfram *is* cool. (According to legend, Stephen Wolfram started the company just so he could do math with the product. :) A trig AI sounds great ... but Wolfram may be way ahead of you. The Wolfram Language is extensive and powerful, and some aspects of it already use AI. (For instance, there's an `ImageIdentify` function. See [Stephen Wolfram's blog post](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2015/05/wolfram-language-artificial-intelligence-the-image-identification-project/) about such stuff.) Of course, that's not to discourage your own work in this area. May you have great success!

Comment: you've understood my way? Is there any way to do in my way?

Answer (score 3):

If I add $1$ to both sides of your first equation then exploit sum-to-product formulas, I'll get$$\frac{\sin2\alpha}{\sin(\alpha-\beta+\gamma)\cos(\alpha+\beta-\gamma)}=\frac{2\sin2\alpha}{\sin2\alpha\cos(-2\beta+2\gamma)}=\frac{\sin(\beta+\gamma)}{\sin\beta\cos\gamma}.$$ If I instead *subtract* $1$ and then re-evaluate, I'll have $$-\frac{\sin(2\gamma-2\beta)}{\cos(\alpha+\beta-\gamma)\sin(\alpha-\beta+\gamma)}=-\frac{\sin(\gamma-\beta)\cos(\gamma-\beta)}{\cos(2\gamma-2\beta)\sin2\alpha}=-\frac{\sin(\beta-\gamma)}{\cos\gamma\sin\beta}.$$

Dividing the two equalities leaves\begin{align}-\frac{\sin2\alpha}{\sin(2\gamma-2\beta)}=\frac{\sin(\beta+\gamma)}{\sin(\gamma-\beta)}\rightarrow-&\sin(\gamma-\beta)\sin2\alpha=2\sin(\beta+\gamma)\sin(\gamma-\beta)\cos(\gamma-\beta)\\
&=\sin(\gamma-\beta)\big(\sin2\gamma+\sin2\beta\,\big),
\end{align}so either $\sin(\gamma-\beta)=0$ or $0=\sin2\alpha+\sin2\beta+\sin2\gamma$.

Comment: $$\frac{\tan x}{\tan y}\pm1=\frac{\sin x\cos y\pm\cos x\sin y}{\cos x\sin y}=\frac{\sin(x\pm y)}{\cos x\sin y}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{\tan C}{\tan B}=\dfrac{\tan(A+(B-C))}{\tan(A-(B-C))}$$

$$\iff\dfrac{\sin C\cos B}{\cos C\sin B}=\dfrac{\sin(A+(B-C))\cos(A-(B-C))}{\sin(A-(B-C))\cos(A+(B-C))}$$

Using [Componendo et Dividendo](http://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Junior%20Secondary/Componendo%20et%20Dividendo.htm),

$$\dfrac{\sin(B+C)}{\sin(B-C)}=\dfrac{\sin2A}{-\sin2(B-C)}$$

$$\implies\sin(B-C)\sin2A=-\sin(B+C)\sin2(B-C)$$

The right hand side can be simplified as

$$=-\sin(B-C)\{2\sin(B+C)\cos(B-C)\}$$

$$=-\sin(B-C)(\sin2B+\sin2C)$$

Comment: I _thought_ the technique I used had a name.

Comment: @AntonioDJC, Are you talking about http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html OR http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Comment: I was referring to _componendo et dividendo_ (which I remembered vaguely from an unrelated proof).

Comment: @labbhattacharjee How you predicted that - $$\frac{\sin (B + C)}{\sin (B - C)} = \frac{\sin 2A}{-\sin 2 (B - C)  }$$ after Compodendo and Dividendo? It has a lot of Variables and functions, so how you calculated whole in your mind?