# Solve: if $\tan (a+b-c)/\tan (a-b+c)=\tan(c)/\tan(b) $, prove that $\sin 2a + \sin 2b + \sin 2c = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

My try : [image]

I can proceed from here but as you all know that it will take more than 1 page , but I want a short approach for it.

Comment: What is $$a,b,c$$ here?

Comment: $$a,b,c$$ stands for the angles

Comment: Angles of a triangle?

Comment: The question have not mentioned that , and also I don't think that

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2783259/if-frac-tanab-c-tana-bc-frac-tan-c-tan-b-then-sinb-c-0-o?rq=1

Comment: OK thanks , Sir

Comment: Sir , I have one homework problem of Progression . Shall I post it on Stack Exchange

Comment: I am not able to do that and even I have posted on many websites but they are not answering it , May be you can help me in this

Comment: Yes you can post it, i hope i can give you a hint!

Comment: Sir, I have posted it , please check